# if $f^r$ is concave then $f$ is concave (r < 0)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I need to prove that the function $e(p,u)=u(p_1^r + p_2^r)^{\frac{1}{r}}$ is concave in $p$ for $r<0$.

So far I could only prove it for $e(p,u)^r$, can I deduce that $e(p,u)$ is concave ?

We know that:

[$f$ concave & $g$ decreasing and concave] $\Rightarrow$ $g\circ f$ is concave

Can we use the reciprocate ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general. Consider $f:\mathbb{R}_{> 0}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$. Note how $(f(x))^{-1}=-1/\sqrt{x}$ is concave but $f(x)$ is convex.

Comment: So for $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=1/x$ we have $h(x)=g \circ f(x)$ is concave, but in this case $g(x)$ is convex (x>0) no ?

Comment: Yes, but it is important to note that $g(x)=1/x$ is nonincreasing. The standard composition rules do not account for this case, so you may need to use some other method to verify concavity in this case. A quick verification of the second derivative of $h(x)=-1/\sqrt{x}$ will show that it is indeed concave.